# What makes a LED a laser diode?

Tags: led, components, laser-diode

High-level survey of this question is fine:

After reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_diode I still can't tell if the electronics that enable a diode to lase are different from those that enable it to emit light. So, in general, is a laser diode a LED *plus* some sort of optical resonator or cavity?

Or are any laser diodes themselves electronically distinct from non-laser LEDs, meaning they don't look like a LED *plus* some extra physical structure to allow them to act as a laser?

Comment: Do you know what makes light a laser?

Comment: Think about it. LEDs already put out nearly pure colors of light. A 'Laser' LED does put out a ultra-pure color of light. Did you bother to search the term "LED Laser"?

Comment: @Sparky256 – Yes, that term is in my search history.  Thank you also for the suggestion that I "Think about it."  That was so helpful I'm going to apply it to questions I have in the future!

Comment: @EugeneSh. – No, but I know the characteristics of laser light.

Answer (score 23):

> I still can't tell if the electronics the enable a diode to lase are different from those that enable it to emit light

It's not the electronics, it's the optical cavity.

If the optical signal is fed back through the gain medium (the PN junction) such that the round trip loss is no more than the round trip gain, an "LED" will start to lase.

A laser diode's cavity can be formed by cleaved facets on the surface of the chip, Bragg reflectors patterned into the chip, or even external lenses and/or mirrors of some kind.

Generally, a device designed as a laser diode will also include a waveguide structure on the chip (and overlapping the junction) to facilitate low round trip loss, while a device designed to be an LED won't have any distinct waveguide structure, though there's also such a thing as a resonant cavity LED (RCLED).

Comment: Interesting.  I can't tell from a quick search what distinguishes RCLEDs: Are they essentially laser diodes operated below the lasing threshold?  Or do they produce *some* but not *all* of the characteristics of laser light?

Comment: I've never worked with RCLEDs, but I get the impression they're mainly used for higher efficiency.

Comment: There is a 'High Efficiency' category of LEDs. It lays flat and is round like a tiny Oreo cookie, emitting light from all sides. It sits in a gold lined bowl which reflects all light to the lens. The lens determines the theta, or viewing angle.

Comment: Also: Laser diodes, when overloaded to a point where that optical cavity structure is busted up, continue to work as normal LEDs!

Comment: @rackandboneman or of course below threshold.  Plenty of cheap ones also age without overloading until they no longer lase.

Comment: My limited reading indicates that RCLEDs are largely distinguished by their [much narrower emission spectrum](https://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~schubert/Light-Emitting-Diodes-dot-org/chap15/F15-06%20RCLED%20ODL50%20Spectrum.jpg) compared to normal LEDs -- but then I'm a spectroscopist so tend to see things from that side.  It's intersting that there's no English Wikipedia article, and the [German one](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonant-cavity_light_emitting_diode) is little more than a stub.

Answer (score 3):

LED: The voltage on the diode lifts the free electrons across the bandgap to a higher level. They emit light when they drop back to the lower level. Due to the rules of quantum mechanics when this happens spontaneously is random if no other measures are taken. The degrees of freedom in a LED allow for variable wavelengths (frequencies) and point in time. Thus the emitted photons are "incoherent".

LASER: The degrees of freedom for the photons are removed. The optical cavity allows only one (or very few) wavelengths (factors of the resonator length). And the previously emitted photons "passing by" stimulate the emission of the new photon. So most photons have the same phase and frequency. They are "coherent".

Even though the LED already has a very small variation of wavelength the LASER optics reduce that variation. The counter intuitive aspect of a LASER comes from quantum mechanics. You might think that a photon is emitted spontaneously and then would resonate if it has the right wavelength that fits the geometry of the resonator. But due to quantum mechanics the geometry of the LASER-(diode) makes it very unlikely for a photon to be emitted spontaneously or at another wavelength.

Comment: My confusion comes in your last paragraph: Is something about the p-n junction itself in a diode laser different?  I.e., is the underlying stimulus for both diodes a spontaneous photon emission, and in the laser the geometry *built around that junction* amplifies those spontaneous emissions to such a degree that the overwhelming majority of photons are emitted by stimulation?  Or is the junction itself in a laser diode different in a way that limits the number and/or wavelength of spontaneously emitted photons, *even below the lasing threshold*?

Comment: When turning on the laser diode initially there are no photons that might stimulate emission. So at first spontaneous emissions happen. Then these go back and forth in the optical cavity and stimulate the emission of more photons and stimulated emission quickly becomes dominating.

Comment: As an afterthought: Stimulated emission might not become "dominating". Spontaneous emissions will continue to happen, but the goal is to have a high percentage of stimulated emission because that defines the efficiency of the laser diode.

Comment: I'm still unclear on the clarification requested in my first comment: It *sounds* like you might be saying, "Yes, the core of a laser diode is (or can be) a p-n junction like any other light emitting diode, which works by spontaneous emission. What makes the diode a laser is *additional* hardware features (which we call an *optical cavity*) that allow those spontaneous photons to stimulate more photons." Is that right? Or is a laser diode *just* an electrically-pumped optical cavity that happens to produce some photons spontaneously, and so is fundamentally different from the "common" LED?

Comment: The laser works by stimulated emission not spontaneous emission. You might want to look at:
http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Semiconductors/diodes_26.php

Answer (score 3):

A diode laser is an LED in an optical cavity.

Diode lasers are kinda cool in that they "violate" a few laser rules:

1. The gain of semiconductors is so great that even though the radius of facets creating the cavity are really high (i.e., essentially flat), it still lases. (The laser equation predicts that infinite gain is necessary for a pair of flat surfaces to lase)!
2. There's a proof that at least three energy levels are needed for a pumped medium to lase, but semiconductor lasers only have two (because they are not optically pumped, but electrically pumped).

Comment: Regarding #2: Would it be accurate to say that diode lasers are "optically *self*-pumped"?  If I understand it: The stimulated emissions are "stimulated" by photons from the LED itself, right?

Comment: Do you have some sources?

Comment: Instead of optically pumped they are electrically pumped. "Pumping" is the process of lifting the electrons over the band gap from which they then can drop down and emit photons.

Comment: @Joachim Corrected to say they're electrically pumped.

Comment: @PeterMortensen my laser class notes from 2006 :S. But any undergrad laser book has this.

Comment: @feetwet In all lasers there must be "stimulated" emission; that is photons knocking off excited photons. What I'm referring to here is the "pumping" the process of putting electrons in an excited state. For a laser to lase there are several conditions one of them is that the gain medium is pumped so much that there are more excited electrons than lower state electrons - population inversion - otherwise you'd have more photons being absorbed putting electrons into higher states than stimulating more photons out.

Comment: On your broken rule #1: A laser diode has flat facets, but it also has an integrated waveguide. You could also make a gas or dye laser lase with flat mirrors, if you included a lens in the cavity to keep the beam from diverging.  On #2: the semiconductor gain medium has many levels in the conduction band, not just one, so this isn't really a 2-level system. Also it's possible to optically pump a semiconductor laser and in fact typically an optically pumped laser is demonstrated before an electrically pumped one in a new material type.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a LED to be considered a "laser" LED, its design must be such that a certain amount of the light it produces **must be reflected** back onto itself, by optical (or electrical) means, so that newly created (via stimulation) photons are **"in step"** with the previous ones, thereby creating a **coherent** beam of photons.
Meeting the **S**timulated **E**mission of **R**adiation requirement, is what makes it a **laser**!